# DNS error on win server 2008 R2

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

After restart of win server 2008 R2 have a problem with DNS role. On DNS I see that primary domain zone is not introduced and there is red cross.

If I look to log I see some ID 4004, say that DNS cannot get information from active directory. Check active directory.

So I check active directory but not see any errors.

So I look again to event Viewer - server DNS: there is a error: 
"DNS Server encountered a critical error from the Active Directory. Check that the Active Directory is functioning properly. Advanced debug error information (which may be empty): 000020EF: SvcErr: DSID-02060237, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data -1017. The error is stored in the data block of the event."

Now I have switched to another DNS.

What I can do? I was wondering to remove and instal DNS role. 
Can any one give me advice?

Thanks A lot

Comment: Um... The DNS service is started?

Comment: Yes, DNS service looks like started. DNS query from PCs work.

Comment: I'm assuming that the DNS server is also the DC and that it's pointing to itself first for DNS. Am I right? If so, point it at your other DC/DNS server first for DNS then at itself. If you don't have another DC/DNS server then you should install one.

Comment: There is one DC Win 2008 R2. On that server is Active directory and DNS. Yes that DC pointing on himselve. But now DNS on DC not working - for main domain zone. So I must change DNS on computer to another DNS on Mikrotik and set A record for dc1.domain.tld. So I need to have working DNS on DC.